# Standardization of index components without mean centering

Tags: standard-deviation, normalization, standardization, composite, index-decomposition

There are many questions and answers ([see here for example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138046/normalizations-dividing-by-mean)) related to standandardization of variables, carried out by taking a value, **subtracting the mean** (centering) and **dividing by standard deviation**.

I do this in an index that has 3 components (x, y, z), **to adjust their scale and make the sum possible**. See here:
$$
R_{i} = \frac{x_{i}-\mu_{x}}{SD_{x}} + \frac{y_{i}-\mu_{y}}{SD_{y}} + \frac{z_{i}-\mu_{z}}{SD_{z}}
$$

My **variables** are all **greater or equal to zero.**

Of course when values are below the mean I get **a negative sum**, which **is a problem**. So I am looking for a way to keep the final index always positive (or zero), as the original variables. But I don't want to use a min-max normalization.

**If I avoid centering, but keep dividing by the SD, do I bias my index?** Is the sum still correct? I mean that the variables have very different scales, so I am wondering if dividing them by SD (without substracting the mean) is enough to make them comparable (and summable).
The result would be like this:

$$
R_{i}^{'} = \frac{x_{i}}{SD_{x}} + \frac{y_{i}}{SD_{y}} + \frac{z_{i}}{SD_{z}}
$$

**MY REASONING TO SAY THAT $R_{i}^{'} $ IS STILL OK**

I think that $R_{i}^{'} $ keeps the ranking of observations as $R_{i}$ and doesn't bias the original index formulation, because mean and SD are constant values, so I would have that the two indices only differ by a constant. See my reasoning here:
$$
k_{x} = \frac{\mu_{x}}{SD_{x}}, k_{y} = \frac{\mu_{y}}{SD_{y}}, k_{z} = \frac{\mu_{z}}{SD_{z}}
$$
so that
$$
R_{i} = \frac{x_{i}}{SD_{x}} - k_{x} + \frac{y_{i}}{SD_{y}} - k_{y} + \frac{z_{i}}{SD_{z}} - k_{z}
$$
and
$$
R_{i} = R_{i}^{'}  - (k_{x}+k_{y}+k_{z})
$$
so I should not have problems using $R_{i}^{'} $ instead of $R_{i}$, as they only differ by a constant.

**HOWEVER I THINK I AM WRONG:** as in this way I am still summing variables on different scales (since I did not subtract the mean, see comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/how-to-sum-two-variables-that-are-on-different-scales/13271#13271)), right? Could a solution be to simply [divide by the mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138046/normalizations-dividing-by-mean)?

Comment: You are not scaling $x_i+y_i+z_i$ by a constant, so may get different results.  What is $R_i$ supposed to represent?

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I get exactly the answer. Numbers will be different, but for example ranking of different observations (i) still concordant? You can imagine the index as an intelligence score, measured along 3 intelligence dimensions.